# Pegar outer html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Como faço para pegar o outerHTML de um objeto jquery? A seguinte forma não está funcionando.

```
$("selector").outerHTML;
```

Comment: Acredito que este tópico vai te ajudar: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5744207/jquery-outer-html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Um objeto jQuery tem dentro uma referência ao elemento nativo que queres e podes extraí-lo com `$('selector')[0]`, a partir daí podes usar JS nativo.

```
var outer = $('selector')[0].outerHTML;
```

Outra opção, é criar um elemento temporário onde se insere o primeiro e se vai buscar o `.html()`. Pode ser que precises desta solução se tiveres vários elementos.

```
var outer = $('<div>').append($('selector').clone()).html();
```

ou ainda, sem ter de clonar:

```
var outer  = $('selector').wrapAll('<div>').parent().html();
```

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
$("selector")[0].outerHTML;
```